# What is the hamburger menu icon called and the three vertical dots icon called?

Tags: button, menu, hamburger-menu

Google and some other developers have introduced us to what some have called the
hamburger menu button and now the 3 vertical dots button or vertical ellipsis. 
What is the official name of these buttons/icons?

It would be nice if developers could consistently use a particular icon for menus.
It would also be nice to know what to tell novice users to press.

**Background Info:**

Horizontal Ellipsis  … `&#8230; &#x2026; &hellip;`

Apple uses the horizontal ellipsis and calls it the 
[More Options](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204839) icon.

According to https://design.google.com/icons/ the icon is called "more horiz".

Vertical Ellipsis ⋮ `&#8942; &#x22EE; &vellip;` 

Google+ for desktop seems to use this as a menu for communities. The Google+ app
uses this icon as a standard menu icon.

According to https://design.google.com/icons/ the icon is called "more vert".

Identical To ≡ `&#8801; &#x2261; &equiv;`

Google Chrome uses an image similar to Identical To and calls it the 
[Chrome menu](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414?hl=en).

It has also been called the "hamburger" icon, "hotdog" icon, Options menu, Menu button,
Overflow menu, Side menu, Menu drawer...

According to https://design.google.com/icons/ the icon is called "menu".

Comment: ☰ is [known as](https://unicode-table.com/en/2630/) the _Trigram for Heaven_ and was approved as part of [Unicode 1.1](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode1.1.0/) in 1993.

Answer (score 111):

Look at this photo, it says "Kebab Menu" is a correct answer:

[image]

per comment below, sourced from Luke Wroblewski: https://twitter.com/lukew/status/591296890030915585/photo/1

Comment: Taken from Luke Wroblewski: https://twitter.com/lukew/status/591296890030915585?lang=en

Comment: +1 on this link. An Apple engineer called out the "Meatball" menu earlier this month on our app, which was the first time I was exposed to that slang term. I would still call them horizontal and vertical ellipsis to any non-technical person.

Comment: It might be offensive to vegans. I suggest "falafel menu" instead.

Comment: I believe Microsoft calls the "Bento" menu a "Waffle" menu although I think its official name is the "Microsoft 365 app launcher."

Answer (score 32):

For the 3 vertical dot icon, these are the most popular names

- Kebab menu
- More options icon

For the remaining, here is the list.

[image: Picture Credit- @MichaelBabich]

Comment: This needs to be updated to reflect three-dots-in-a-circle-menu, popularised by HIG Gods from Cupertino, and now also by Gods from Redmond. I propose Meatballs Plate Menu.

Answer (score 19):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3es1p3/what_is_the_three_dots_ellipsis_menu_actually/?st=j6wb7r8i&sh=dee2ca5f), **more options icon** and **kabob menu** are popular names.  I prefer the latter as it goes well with hamburger menu.

Comment: I believe the spelling is "kebab".

Comment: @wildbagel According to Google, it's "shish kabob".

Comment: And according to Wikipedia, it's kebab: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kebab
But to your point, it looks like kabob is an accepted English spelling.

Answer (score 14):

Cannot say about the "official nomenclature" - infact I wonder whose word will be "official" anyway - but here's how they can be called:

- **Horizontal stripes** : Hamburger menu / icon / button -> [image] -> as per [*wiki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button). A name like "sandwich button" would also have been good IMO :(
- **Vertical ellipsis** : Dango  menu / icon / button -> [image] -> [*credits to this guy*](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3es1p3/what_is_the_three_dots_ellipsis_menu_actually/cti898x/). This one I like thanks to the [song from the super duper anime Clannad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvzCmV3_12c&index=44&list=PLyf7jJ6pvWdu1-DoMCJV8GxqDO8pIWO_p) [image]

Answer (score 4):

Not an official name per se, but I've heard vertical ellipsis referred to as "snowman" in SAS community.

Answer (score 2):

We call it the "ant" menu. Guess it was a good time to change since everyone had just gotten used to the hamburger.

Comment: @SalmanA : We're all "someone else" to someone else
 - Calvin's dad (http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1989/05/02)

Answer (score 0):

At eBay it’s the kabob.

Also heard it called the snowman or sushi roll.